# Android: ListView updates wrongly on database delete

Tags: android, sqlite, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

When I delete a row from the sqlite table, the ListView is always updating with removing the last entry. When restarting the activity it reflects the database content correctly.

This is how I delete a row from the table (mDb is a SQLiteOpenHelper object):

```
mDb.delete(TABLE, COL_ID + "=" + id, null);
mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(DB_URI, null);
```

And this is how the List is updated (simplified). I have verified that onLoadFinished() is called.

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

…

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.calllist);

        String[] from = new String[] { … };
        int[] to = new int[] { ... };

        notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0){
    }


    public final static class MyCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {
        final Loader.ForceLoadContentObserver observer = new ForceLoadContentObserver();

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(SELECT_ALL, null);
            c.registerContentObserver(this.observer);
            c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), DB_URI);
            return c;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        if (loader.getId() == LOADER_ID) {
            notes.changeCursor(cursor);
            notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I seems to work when I delay the notifyChange(DB_URI, null) call with a second or more. Should that be necessary? Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CursorLoader instead. See [Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html)

Comment: That would mean that I have to implement a ContentProvider as well, right?

Comment: CursorLoaders works with ContentProviders ... it seems like he do not have ContentProvider(he is using plain Cursors) ... that is why i think it is not a valid answer